# Flip real time video and stop it with user input

Tags: matlab, user-interface, video, mirror

I created a GUI using Matlab and inserted a live video in this GUI with 2 bush buttons, one for starting video and the other for capturing an image.

The problem is when I press start video, the video displays the picture flipped, it means when you wave right hand, it is displayed in the left side.

how can I solved this problem?
I wrote this code:

```
 i=0;

while(i<=1000)

dataa=getsnapshot(vid);
data1 = dataa(:,:,1);
data1 = fliplr(data1);
 data2 = dataa(:,:,2);
data2 = fliplr(data2);
 data3 = dataa(:,:,3);
data3 = fliplr(data3);
data=cat(3,data1,data2,data3);
flushdata(vid);
imshow(data);

 end
```

and it works, but now I want to stop the while statement when the user pushes a button. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: cant you flipit manually? I mean, using fliplr().

Comment: Thank you for you comment, I used it but there is a problem. I edited my question, you van see it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `fliplr()` function to flip your frames when you capture them to flip them. As long as I know, this code is quite fast as it doesnt flip the positions but changes the matrix element memory directions.

For stoping the while loop I suggest the next thing (maybe a more experienced matlab "player" would do it something else)

Wherever you have the code do:

```
while (i<=1000)&&~buttonpushed

% your code

pause(0.01)  % If you dont pause the loop the GUI cannot refresh
 end
```

In the startup part of the code

```
global buttonpushed;
buttonpushed=false;
```

And In the callback of the button:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

   if get(hObject,'Value')
       buttonpushed=true;
   else
      buttonpushed=false;
   end

end
```

Comment: @Naaan987 Accept the answer as valid then, so future people can see how to solve the problem.